# How can I select a row count into a field for each row of the result set?

Tags: mysql, count

Sorry for the question (not for asking it, but for the way it's worded - I'm not... entirely certain how to ask it...).

I'm running the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    `U`.`user_id`                           AS `User_ID`
    /*A lot of irrelevant stuff*/
    COUNT(`U`.`parent_id` = `U`.`user_id`)  AS `SubAccounts_Active` #This is the part of the statement with which I'm having trouble.
    /*More non-relevant stuff*/             
FROM `users` AS `U`;
    /*Non-relevant join.*/
```

The bit of SQL on which I commented (`COUNT(U.parent_id = U.user_id)`) I had initially as just `0`.

I need, for each row, to count the number of rows in which the field `parent_id` matches the field `user_id` from the table `users`.

I thought the SQL I had would do the job but it flattens the result set into a single row and that won't work for me (I'd forgotten that `COUNT` and `SUM` both flatten the result set (been a while since I've done anything with SQL so I'm not sure what the technical term for that is, but I digress...)) - I need the total for each row (`user`) to be present within the defined field (`SubAccounts_Active`).

What SQL would I need to employ to achieve this result?

### EDIT 1

Thanks to the suggestion I received in the first comment I was able to stumble my way through to the following SQL that returned the proper result set -

```
SELECT
    `U`.`user_id`                           AS `User_ID`,
    COUNT(`C`.`parent_id` = `U`.`user_id`)  AS `SubAccounts_Active`
FROM `users` AS `U`
LEFT JOIN `users`                           AS `C`
    ON `C`.`parent_id` = `U`.`user_id`
GROUP BY `U`.`user_id`;
```

This returned the result set I was expecting where the count of each parent accounts children was set in the SubAccounts_Active field.

Comment: You'll need to JOIN users to itself, and aggregate functions only "flatten" when GROUP BY is omitted.

Comment: Your suggestion nailed it - thanks for your help. If you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN and a count:

```
SELECT
  `U`.`user_id`                           AS `User_ID`,
  /* A lot of irrelevant stuff */
  COUNT(U2.user_id) AS SubAccounts_Active
FROM
  `users` AS `U` LEFT JOIN `users` AS `U2`
  ON u.parent_id=u2.user_id
GROUP BY
  `U`.`user_id`,
  /* other fields */
```

U2.user_id will be null when the join doesn't succed, and non-null otherwise. COUNT will always count all of the rows where u.parent_id=u2.user_id.

Comment: You are correct (and your SQL pretty much matches that which I devised while being less complex).

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6707/2

```
SELECT
    p.user_id AS User_ID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.user_id)  AS SubAccounts_Active
FROM users AS p 
LEFT JOIN users c 
ON p.user_id = c.parent_id
GROUP BY p.user_id
```